# BPS States and Conditions: Definition and Significance in the Context of ADS/CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, ads-cft

I am currently studying a paper similar to the one [linked](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0407277) and I'm struggling to comprehend the concept of BPS (Bogomol'nyi-Prasad-Sommerfield) states/operators. The cited papers mention these terms without providing any clear explanation, and my attempts to find a comprehensive introduction or definition of BPS sector/operators/states/conditions have been unsuccessful. Moreover, the ADS/CFT literature appears to be somewhat convoluted in this regard.

- Could someone provide an explanation of what a BPS condition entails?

I assume that BPS states are states that satisfy these conditions, but I am unclear on the specifics. That's why

- I am interested in understanding why BPS states are considered particularly useful or relevant in the field.

If possible, I would appreciate any suggestions for reliable literature or resources that offer a comprehensive treatment of this topic.